# .htaccess apache env var not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables

i want to setup in my .htaccess apache file the env var for mobile

i have:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent "iPhone" devicetype
SetEnvIf User-Agent "Android" devicetype
RewriteRule ^ - [E=DEVICE:%{devicetype}]
```

but my $_SERVER['DEVICE'] is always empty. why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You rule will set the `$_SERVER['devicetype']`

`[devicetype] => 1`

you don't need: `RewriteRule ^ - [E=DEVICE:%{devicetype}]`

If you prefer, you can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|android" [NC] # i put 2 as example
RewriteRule ^ - [E=DEVICE:mobile]
```

This will set $_SERVER['DEVICE'] to `mobile`